# JQUERY Recalculate the sum after dragging new items

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to calculate the total of elements dragged in the right column. It kinda work, but it's only calculating the 2 default elements in that column. If I drag new items, the total stays the same.
I made this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehkgcnyp/

```
$( function() {
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();

// Calculate badges
var sum = 0.0;
$('#sortable2 .badge-pill').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
//alert(sum);
$('#getTotal').click(function() {
  $('#grandTotal').html(sum);
});
});
```

How do I take in account new items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem what that you calculated the result when pages was loaded and not when your clicked the button.

I've changed your code a bit to this:

```
 function sum() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#sortable2 .badge-pill').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    return sum;
  }

  //alert(sum);
  $('#getTotal').click(function() {
    $('#grandTotal').html(sum());
  });
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();

  // Calculate badges
  function sum() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#sortable2 .badge-pill').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    return sum;
  }

  //alert(sum);
  $('#getTotal').click(function() {
    $('#grandTotal').html(sum());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable list-group">
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Item 1 <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Item 2 <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Item 3 <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Item 4 <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable list-group">
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Drag items here</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Item 4 <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Item 5 <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-6">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <button id="getTotal" type="button" name="button" class="calculate btn btn-primary btn-lg">Calculate</button>
        <h2 id="grandTotal">0</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```